# Calculations wrong

Tags: c#, decimal, calculator

I am trying to create a simple C# calculator for fun. Im having a problem where the calculator is giving me wrong results and i can't find anything wrong with my code.

For example if try to calculate the following calculation **15+12** it gives me a result of **30** instead of **27** which is the correct answer.

Here is my code; any help will be appreciated as im kind of new to coding.

```
namespace Calculator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            resultBox.Text += "=";
        }

        //Function Add
        private void button_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            funcBox.Clear();
            funcBox.Text += "+";
        }

        //Function Subtract
        private void button_subtract_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            funcBox.Clear();
            funcBox.Text += "-";
        }

        //Function Multiply
        private void button_mult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            funcBox.Clear();
            funcBox.Text += "*";
        }

        //Function Divide
        private void button_div_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            funcBox.Clear();
            funcBox.Text += "/";
        }


        //Clear button
        private void button_clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            numBox1.Clear();
            numBox2.Clear();
            funcBox.Clear();
            resultBox.Clear();
            resultBox.Text += "= ";  
        }

        private void getResult(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Check if the both numboxes and funcbox contains something
            if (numBox1.Text.Length > 0 && numBox2.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                if (funcBox.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    resultBox.Clear();
                    resultBox.Text += "= ";

                    decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);
                    decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);

                    decimal result = CalculateResult(num1, num2);
                    resultBox.Text += result;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No function selected.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You can't leave empty fields.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }

        }

        //Calculate the result
        public decimal CalculateResult(decimal num1, decimal num2)
        {
            decimal res = 0;

            if (funcBox.Text == "+")
            {
                res = num1 + num2;
            }
            else if (funcBox.Text == "-")
            {
                res = num1 - num2;
            }
            else if (funcBox.Text == "*")
            {
                res = num1 * num2;
            }
            else if (funcBox.Text == "/")
            {
                res = num1 / num2;
            }

            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger, Luke!

Comment: Try : resultBox.Text += result.ToString();

Comment: decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);
decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);

Hence 15+15 = 30

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning same value for both `num1` and `num2`

```
decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);
decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);<- here is the issue, change to numBox2 instead
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think your problem is in this two lines:

```
decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);
decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);
```

'num' should be associated with numBox2 right?

Answer (score 0):

In getResult function you have a problem:

```
decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);
decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);
```

should be

```
decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);
decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(numBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like num1 and num2 are parsed at the same time:

```
decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);
decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text); // Parses same text
```

should be:

decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(numBox1.Text);

decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(**numBox2**.Text);